# System of simultaneous equations $x^n+y^n+z^n=3$ ($n$=1,2,5)

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

Does someone know the solution of the following system of simultaneous equations ($x$, $y$, $z$ are real numbers):

$$
x+y+z=3
$$
$$
x^2+y^2+z^2=3
$$
$$
x^5+y^5+z^5=3
$$

Presented at one of math competitions, don't remember when and where.

Comment: I guess, x=y=1 is the only solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$ x+y+z=3$$ Is a plane which contains the point $(1,1,1)$ and has a normal vector $(1,1,1)$. In other words it is a tangent plane to the sphere at the point $(1,1,1)$. This will then be the only point of intersection between the plane and the sphere; no other point can be a solution to the system as a whole.

Since the point $(1,1,1)$ also solves the third equation it turns out to be a solution of the system.

Comment: Simple and great! So the last equation is redundant after all! This suggests an algebraic solution given below.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the algebraic solution. Consider z as parameter, so we have

$$
x+y=3-z
$$
$$
x^2+y^2=3-z^2
$$

Subtracting second equation from first *squared* gives:
$$
2xy=6-6z+2z^2
$$

or
$$
xy=z^2-3z+3
$$

Roots of the system

$$
x+y=3-z
$$
$$
xy=z^2-3z+3
$$

are the roots of polynomial

$$
t^2-(3-z)t+(z^2-3z+3)
$$

which has real roots if
$$
(3-z)^2-4(z^2-3z+3) \ge 0
$$

Simplifying the LHS expression gives:

$$
-3(z-1)^2 \ge 0
$$

or
$$
(z-1)^2 \le 0
$$

which may happen only if $z=1$.

Substituting $z=1$ gives $x=y=1$